# What do you call a collection of coordinated servers?

Tags: phrase-requests, technology

A "network" is any collection of server machines that are physically connected and/or can see each other.

Now consider some subset of those servers that are configured to coordinate with each other. One might be an authentication server, another a database server, and two are application servers that rely on the first two for SSO, application data and maybe shared inter-application data.

To the end-user there is one "thing" offering multiple services. What single word or phrase is the name of this thing?

For example, "The [coordinated subnet] provides the chat service."

Comment: This question belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kris as a general rule for questions about software/IT terminology? in that case maybe Server Fault is an even better fit

Comment: Not as a general rule but for better prospects. Where you ask makes a significant difference to what you get.

Answer (score 3):

What you have just described sounds very similar to the concept of [**computer cluster**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster):

> A computer cluster is a set of loosely or tightly connected computers that work together so that, in many respects, they can be viewed as a single system.

In your case, there is absolutely nothing stopping you from calling a computer cluster a server cluster since the concepts are strikingly similar.

Your example:

> The **server cluster** provides the chat service.

Comment: hmmm, but servers in a cluster are homogenous: "computer clusters have each node set to perform the same task, controlled and scheduled by software", and a "grid computer" (heterogeneous nodes) is treated as a single computing entity - that kinda fits, but I expect the subnet to have multiple network endpoints so I'm not sure if suitable

Comment: I think this is incorrect (see above) but clearly in the right direction, thanks

Comment: @d3vid If you are being particular, you might prefer the term **server farm**, which *can* be a cluster, but can also have servers that perform different tasks. However, you'll find that the definition of what servers do in a farm (or even a cluster) are typically be the same specific thing, but don't always have to be. Look [here](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/server-farm-Web-farm-Web-server-farm). Aside from that, coordinated servers are referred to by their *function*: *administrative servers*, *mail servers*, *internet servers*, and so on.

Comment: @d3vid A small and heterogeneous group can also be referred to as *local servers*.